# How to use a Favicon when creating a shortcut to an URL

Tags: windows, shortcuts, favicon

If I create a shortcut on my Desktop using

```
Right Click < New < Shortcut
```

Then entering am address like http://www.mytest.com is there anyway for this to grab the favicon used and use it for the icon on desktop automatically or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Save your icon image(s) as .png format, then use this tool to compile them into a single .ico file:

png2ico - PNG to icon converter (Linux, Unix, GNU, Windows, ...)
  http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/

The beauty of this tool (and tools like it) are that it can save multiple sizes in a single .ico file so that the destination can display the size that fits best (e.g., if a user enlarges the icon view, the higher resolution size can be displayed instead of the tiny one enlarged for a better quality image).

This is a command-line tool, which is also nice for automation purposes, but also because then you have complete control over what's going on, which is not always typical of GUIs.